# select an option using selenium with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

i have problem to select an option with selenium using python
so i need to select for exemaple Fiction and than select General or General and Action&Adventure and General ...... like in the image i try to do it with this code and it not work

[image]

```
el = driver.find_element_by_id('icon-fiction')
for option in el.find_elements_by_tag_name('General'):
          if option.text == 'General':
              option.click() # select() in earlier versions of webdriver
                   break
```

website for html  :https://kdp.amazon.com/en_US/title-setup/paperback/new/details?openid.assoc_handle=amzn_dtp&openid.claimed_id=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2Fap%2Fid%2Famzn1.account.AG7HI6NMSZIPA7QVZPQKJ3I6XJOQ&openid.identity=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2Fap%2Fid%2Famzn1.account.AG7HI6NMSZIPA7QVZPQKJ3I6XJOQ&openid.mode=id_res&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.op_endpoint=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2Fap%2Fsignin&openid.response_nonce=2020-12-17T15%3A56%3A46Z9038863170341944154&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fkdp.amazon.com%2Fen_US%2Ftitle-setup%2Fpaperback%2Fnew%2Fdetails&openid.signed=assoc_handle%2Cclaimed_id%2Cidentity%2Cmode%2Cns%2Cop_endpoint%2Cresponse_nonce%2Creturn_to%2CsiteState%2Cns.pape%2Cpape.auth_policies%2Cpape.auth_time%2Csigned&openid.ns.pape=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fextensions%2Fpape%2F1.0&openid.pape.auth_policies=http%3A%2F%2Fschemas.openid.net%2Fpape%2Fpolicies%2F2007%2F06%2Fnone&openid.pape.auth_time=2020-12-17T15%3A56%3A46Z&openid.sig=gOkoW0ub6BFnN1IpGrJ2zRNNYa2dTXh82BTqK65%2FV%2B8%3D&serial=&siteState=clientContext%3D130-9751139-1668663%2CsourceUrl%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fkdp.amazon.com%252Fen_US%252Ftitle-setup%252Fpaperback%252Fnew%252Fdetails%253Fref_%253Dkdp_kdp_BS_D_cr_ti%2526ref_%253Dkdp_kdp_BS_D_cr_ti%2Csignature%3DUPj2F2xIPgi34ORsFkbJcj2FXq5l8pAj3D

Comment: please add html of general  , the scrteen shot doesnt give information on that

Comment: thank u for remember me a mention the website

Answer (score 0):

Simply open the fiction and then target the input tag.

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(),'Choose categories')]"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Fiction']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='General']//preceding-sibling::input"))).click()
```

Imports

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: it dose't work i have this erreur when i played your code :Message: element click intercepted: Element <button id="data-print-book-categories-button-proto-announce" class="a-button-text" type="button">...</button> is not clickable at point (420, 647). Other element would receive the click: <div class="a-modal-scroller a-declarative" data-action="a-popover-floating-close" style="padding-bottom: 0px; visibility: visible;">...</div>